# Writing Data to a .txt File

Tags: python, string, variables

I am trying to write data to a text file in python and I am trying to get the user to choose the name of the file as a string. However when it comes to actually writing the data, it shows an error.

```
import random
name = input("Please enter your name: ")
clas = input("Please enter what class you are in: ")
#Uses a list to show the 3 operators I want to use
ops = ['+', '-', '*']
#Defines two variables as 1 and 0
x = 1
score = 0
#While the variable x is less than or equal to 10, the loop will continue
while x <= 10:
    #Selects 2 random integers from 1 to 10
    num1 = random.randint(1,10)
    num2 = random.randint(1,10)
    #Choses the operation from the list `ops`
    operation = random.choice(ops)
    #Prints the 2 numbers and operation in an arithmetic question layout
    print(num1,operation,num2)
    maths = int(eval(str(num1) + operation + str(num2)))
    #Gets the user to input there answer to the question
    answer = int(input("What is the answer to  that arithmetic question? "))
    #If the answer the user input is equal to the correct answer the user scores a point and is told it is correct
#Otherwise, the answer must be wrong so the user is told his score is incorrect and that no points are scored
if answer == maths:
    print ("Correct")
    score += 1
else:
    print ("Incorrect Answer")
#Add one onto the score that the while loops depends on to make sure it only loops 10 times
x = x + 1
#Leaves the iteration after 10 loops and prints the users final score
print ("You scored", score, " out of 10 points")
score2 = str(score)    
score = str(name + score2 + "\n")
with open(clas."txt", "a") as scorefile:
scorefile.write(score)
```

Comment: Please post the error along with your code

Comment: Invalid Syntax, line 34

Comment: You need to tab over the scorefile.write(score) line one more

Comment: `with open(clas."txt", "a")` seems odd to me. try `clas+".txt"`

Comment: Is there a way to sort the data I've scored alphabetically, averages etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write to a file:

```
f = open("filename.txt","w")
f.write("Writing to a file!")
# writes "Writing to a file!" as a new line in filename.txt
f.close()
```

To read a file:

```
f = open("filename.txt","r")
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
print lines
# prints array
```

**Make sure to use f.close(), otherwise bad things will happen**.